# I want to save Image from ImagePicker to SharedPreferences - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this piece of code. I want to store the image that the user picked from the gallery or took by camera (ImagePicker) to SharedPreferences, but I don't know how to do it.

```
File? image;

  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) return;

      final imagePermenant = await saveImagePermenantly(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imagePermenant;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to pick image:$e");
    }
  }

  Future takePhoto() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (image == null) return;

      final imagePermenant = await saveImagePermenantly(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imagePermenant;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to take photo:$e");
    }
  }

  Future<File> saveImagePermenantly(String imagePath) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final name = basename(imagePath);
    final image = File("${directory.path}/$name");

    return File(imagePath).copy(image.path);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you save images into `sharedpreferences`.
as documentation said, it only support to save `String`, `int`, `bool`  [[here]](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

but if you want to try, you can convert your image to String (`base64`) and save it. but it will be a very long `String`.

```dart
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 // convert your image to base64.
 String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
 // store the image
 prefs.setString("image", base64Image);
```